# How to capture screen after applying mask to the layer in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, capture, layer

I added two UIView to ViewController.view, and applied 2 squares image into each view.layer.mask to make it like a square is sliced into 2 pieces, and addSubview the imageview over it.
 I am having a problem rendering the masked layers and save it to photo album. 
I want the saved photo to be look like picture no. 1, but it always looks like picture no. 2 after I save it to photo album. 
 Is there any solution to capture like picture No. 1 after applying mask?

the below is the reference from apple regarind renderIngContext.

Important The OS X v10.5 implementation of this method does not support the entire Core Animation composition model. QCCompositionLayer, CAOpenGLLayer, and QTMovieLayer layers are not rendered. Additionally, layers that use 3D transforms are not rendered, nor are layers that specify backgroundFilters, filters, compositingFilter, or a mask values. Future versions of OS X may add support for rendering these layers and properties.

[image]

Comment: just capture screenShot of window...not the view... according to your query..

Comment: Sorry but as you mentioned, when i capture window it looks like no 2

Comment: can you please tell me about the line in no1...what is this?

Comment: it's a square cutted into 2 pieces. applied masking image to view.layer.mask

Comment: Have you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we apply masking to any image then the we get the resultant image with alpha property of masked image to 1 and remaining image to 0,
and when we are capturing image of view then there is still complete image(we are able to seen half image due due to alpa = 0 of half image, but there is still a complete image) , so we getting the screenshot of complete view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I just edited my question a little. Could you please read it 1more time and see if you could help me solve this? thank you

Comment: i did a lot but when we capture image then we get image of complete view...there in the line is of alpha = 0 but there is an image back side of it....which is not visible due to masking but present in back...

Answer (score 1):

I've created an image capture function before, which literally does a printscreen of a UIView. I don't use it, because it does not work well for my needs but maybe you can use it:

```
UIImage *img;   

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIViewYouWantToCapture.bounds.size, self.opaque, 0.0);
[[UIViewYouWantToCapture layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: @tulurira Hi, worked anything for you to capture? Can i get some help on it how to capture  a snapshot from a layer on a view?